# Trying to validate com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead.ReadMultiStream using ZipInputStream

Tags: java, rest, jersey, zip

I've been checking some code lately about a functionality that is not working and it is related of a process of uploading a file through a Jersey REST Service.

Here is the REST method signature:

```
@POST
@Path("tickets/attachments")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public AttachmentFileInformation uploadFile(
                                            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                                            @FormDataParam("filename") String filename)
```

The objective of this REST is to save the attachment into file system and the database (something that is already done without issues). The problem is that, I've recently checked that there's a validation to check if the file is a ZIP file and also the validation includes some code to check if the ZIP file contains ".exe" or ".sh" extensions inside. But this is not working. The basic code I found for this is the following:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(uploadedInputStream);
```

And then the code tries to iterate over the contents to check the file:

```
ZipEntry entry;
while (( entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)...
```

The problem is that the loop never starts, like the zip file is empty. Then I made some debug and found that the inputstream we receive is from type: [com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead.ReadMultiStream](http://j6a.ru/classcom_1_1sun_1_1xml_1_1internal_1_1org_1_1jvnet_1_1mimepull_1_1_data_head_1_1_read_multi_stream.html)

So I tried to correct this by converting the stream to a byte array and then use it for the ZipInputStream, like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
  baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
baos.flush();
byte[] zipBytes =  baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes));
```

But when I logged the "zipBytes" length, I found that  the size is "0".

I wonder to know how can I handle this type of validation for this specific type of InputStream.

I'll keep on checking how to perform the conversion but if somebody can post a clue of what is going on here, I'll really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing similar kind of issue when trying to call another rest service with inputstream as parameter

```
public void create(@FormDataParam("attachmentDTO") String attachmentItem,
        @FormDataParam("attachmentFile") InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("attachmentFileName") String attachmentFileName) {
        File file = new File(attachmentFileName); 
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("attachmentDTO", attachmentItem);
```

//        body.add("attachmentFile", inputStream); -- replacing this line with below line would solve my problem

```
    body.add("attachmentFile", file);        

    body.add("attachmentFileName", attachmentFileName);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(body);
    String URL = "http://google.com";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, request, String.class);
    }
```

getting below error message

```
no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream]
```

So to solve this issue, we have 2 solutions

- Instead of passing inputstream as parameter we are now passing "new
  File(attachmentFileName)", here attachmentFileName contains the
  absolute path of the file
- Create a new file at your location and copy the content from
  inputStream to new file as below

  File newFile = new File(path);
  FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, newFile);